# What is the best way to display multiple PDF files via browser?

Tags: java, performance, jsp, pdf, web-applications

I'm developing an web application using Flex and JSP.

I am having some performance issues with displaying multiple PDF files.
I am trying to display about 50-100 PDF files. I know that is a little crazy.
Hence, I made the project to convert PDF files to JPG format and display the JPG files.

I'm wondering if there is a way to decrease the file size of PDF to size of JPG.

Additionally, I would like to seek other way that may improve the performance.

Does anyone know a good way to display many PDF files (that will be mostly just text) for web application? Or, should I just have it display JPG files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PDF files are mostly text you should probably use HTML.  Is there something that would prevent you from making regular pages from your PDFs?

Comment: Yes, these are files that get uploaded from users. The typical end users are teachers who will scan papers (that usually give PDF format) and upload them for students. There are other details but that's what preventing me from simply using HTML.

Comment: In that case rather than display them why not have your users download them.  That way you can just have a web page effectively be a file browser.  You could take a snapshot/thumbnail of the first page so they know what they are going to be getting.

Comment: The PDF files are for associating students with their tests. The teacher will need to associate students with the corresponding exams. In order to do that, teacher needs to see the name on the PDF file. this process can be eliminated if I can find a way to do hand writing recognition

Comment: I'm thinking of how to keep it small. If the name is in a consistent place then all you really need convert and show on your web site is the name page as a thumbnail. You can then put the PDF behind a link for download.  Would that work?

Comment: do you mean make a thumbnail PDF file?
or conver to jpg and make the thumbnail?

Comment: I guess I can go ahead and do the 2nd part, but now I'm wondering if first option is feasible

Comment: What I had in mind was that you make a jpg of the name page of the pdf and show that on your web page as an identifier for the pdf. The user can then identify the student from the jpg, click on the image and download the pdf.

Comment: Another approach may be to have the student provide their name and the name of the paper when they upload it.  That way you don't need any of this effort, you can just present their names and paper titles and a link to the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the PDF to rtf text file, use the text from rtf file to populate your HTML page perhaps in a table.

Check out **ghostscript**  lib for doing this conversion.

Comment: This is not recommended because if the PDF files do include images or diagrams (although that does not happen all the time).

Comment: You can generate gif or jpeg from the PDF by using ghostscript. I guess image will be the way to go for your requirement.